# Is the capped hole in a paint bucket lid meant to be a pour spout?

Tags: painting

So, I bought this 5-gal jug of Behr paint from HD.  It was economical to buy in bulk and it has (what I thought was) a convenient pour spout on the top.  I try to keep paint cans and lids clean when I paint so its easy to save leftover paint for future projects. From the look of it, you could open only the smaller lid to pour.

[image]

But after trying to pour into a paint tray with it I began to suspect that it was rather intended for the employees to add tint without breaking the larger seal.  When I poured, the paint came out so slowly that a bunch of it dribbled into the well in which the lid seats.

Does there exist a device that would make pouring from this smaller opening possible?  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Paint can be poured using only that small opening but yes, it's messy.  I've found it helps to pour quickly.

The retailer where you purchased this likely has a screw-on spout extension that will help.  If not, check around at other paint retailers.

Something like this:

[image: Paint Spout]

Comment: Ahh, that looks like just the ticket!

Comment: Yup.  It was maybe $3 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Where do you have the smaller hole positioned when pouring? The right way is counterintuitive to most people. It should be UP so that air can flow in as paint flows out. As the paint level gets lower you can turn it to the side.

It would not exactly shock me to find that someone has made a screw in spout with an air tube for these, but I'm not looking for it.

Would also work well for a suction tube feed - pump fed roller or sprayer.

Hard to stir the paint properly without taking the lid off, once you get it home from the store and don't have a paint-shaker handy, so probably of limited use if not using it all at once for a big project. And if storing it for a long time, you may find the size a false economy, as partly full paint cans/pails tend to go bad a lot faster than full ones - but you could fill up smaller ones if the price of the paint is the thing.

Comment: Same with engine oil bottles, incidentally.

Comment: Yes, I was pouring upside down, with the pour spout nearer to the bottom.  I'm sure it would work better to try it the other way.  I've often been able to reuse paint in old jugs by VERY carefully lifting off the top layer of paint that has dried.  Most of it I plan to use within a few weeks so I think the economy is there.  Thanks for the upside down tip though!

Comment: & Olive oil cans, as well.

Comment: For stirring I have an attachment for my drill that does wonders.

Comment: Also I did take the advice of storing the 2 gals I didn't use in 1-gallon paint cans.  Although the cans were fairly expensive,  so not sure if the jumbo paint was worth it.